# php count tab occurrence in string

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to count the occurrences of tab characters in a string.

```
substr_count("this    means   nothing", "\t");
```

returns 0, but I expect two tab stops in my test string.

I don't want to use regex if possible (for performance reasons).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `substr_count()` with `"\t"` works perfectly.

Comment: Your Editor might convert tabs into spaces when you save.

Comment: Your tabs aren't tabs but 4 spaces. Maybe your editor converts tabs to spaces?

Answer (score 1):

```
$text2 = 'this    means   nothing';
echo substr_count($text2, 't');
```

Try it
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,

like Friedrich Roell commented, my editor converted tabs to spaces indeed.

substr_count() works fine.

Thanks at all.